# Requested URL not found - Laravel 6

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-6

I am trying to upload a my project to the server.the first page is working properly and when i go for another page am getting error like `The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 142.93.209.171 Port 80`. i think the problem is at `.htaccess` file,here is my `.htaccess` file placed in the public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my `app_url` placed in `.env` file

```
APP_URL=http://142.**.***.***/
```

Here is the virtual host configuration

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/studio/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/studio/public>
     Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

i tried a lot but always getting `404` error

Comment: Please provide your virtual host configuration. Do you have AllowOverride set?

Comment: i had searched virtual host configuration in the server but its not visible,  where will be the virtual host configuration in server section

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

Comment: i had added it.

Comment: Are you certain that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server?

Comment: After setting up all changes restart your Apache services ?

Comment: it's got cleared by enabling the `mod_rewrite`. Thankful to every one